# Laravel Firebird Error "invalid request BLR at offset"

Tags: laravel, user-defined-functions, firebird

I'm trying to connect to .fdb using [package](https://packagist.org/packages/harrygulliford/laravel-firebird) in my web-app

settings:

```
'firebird' => [
        'driver'   => 'firebird',
        'host'     => 'localhost',
        'port'     => '3050',
        'database' => storage_path('db.fdb'),
        'username' => 'SYSDBA',
        'password' => 'masterkey',
        'charset'  => 'UTF8',
        'version'  => '2.5', // 1.5 - same
        'role'     => null,
        'UdfAccess' => 'Full', // try like DBeaver connection
        'isc_dpb_no_db_triggers' => true, // try like DBeaver connection
],
```

controller:

```
$fb = DB::connection('firebird')->table('table')->count();
```

result:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [335544343] invalid request BLR at offset 132 (SQL: select count(*) as "aggregate" from "TABLE").

Full error is

> invalid request BLR at offset 132 function POS is not defined module name or entrypoint could not be found

What is my problem? How to ignore UDF or turn it on?

Win 10, x64, have Firebird 2.5 and 3.

Have the same problem in C# app.

Comment: What is the full error, what is the DDL of the table or view?

Comment: As an aside, you should not normally use `isc_dpb_no_db_triggers` (assuming your connection library even supports it like that), it defeats the entire purpose of having db triggers.

Comment: Are you sure that is the full error, invalid request BLR is usually a multi-line error (e.g. _"invalid request BLR at offset 623\nfunction LRTRIM is not defined\nmodule name or entrypoint could not be found"_)

Comment: In any case, you need to identify which UDF is missing (likely it is used in a calculated column or in the view definition), and then either make sure the right UDF is available, or remove the usage of that UDF. So, please show the DDL of the table (or view) involved in your query.

Comment: In exception of web-app that is full error.
In C#: + function POS is not defined module name...
Table has a few triggers and many depends. Can`t show.

Comment: What is the output of `select RDB$FUNCTION_NAME, RDB$MODULE_NAME, RDB$ENTRYPOINT from RDB$FUNCTIONS rf where RDB$FUNCTION_NAME = 'POS'`, and what is the DDL of the table, I'm just asking about the table itself, not its triggers or anything else. Or if you can't or don't want to show the entire table, does it have any computed columns (`computed by` or `generated always as`), if so what is their expression.

Comment: RDB$FUNCTION_NAME = POS; RDB$MODULE_NAME = DMM_UDF; RDB$ENTRYPOINT = ibPos; computed by or generated always - none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your database has a UDF definition (`POS`), but cannot find or load the UDF library (or the library doesn't contain the function entrypoint). This can happen if you moved your database to a different server, but forgot to move/install the accompanying UDF libraries, or if you're using a different version of the UDF library (one that doesn't contain the function entrypoint).

There are basically two ways to recover from this:

1. Make sure your database server has the appropriate UDF library
2. Remove any usage of the UDF from your database.

#### Option 1

Your `POS` UDF uses the `DMM_UDF` library (which doesn't sounds familiar to me, so it is likely a custom UDF library) with the `ibPos` entry point. On windows, this library would generally be called `DMM_UDF.dll` or `dmm_udf.dll`.

Find the right UDF DLL file (e.g. on the old database server), and make sure it has the same bitness as your Firebird server. If you only have a 32-bit version, replace your 64-bit Firebird server with a 32-bit Firebird server.

You need to add this DLL to the `udf` directory of your Firebird installation, and make sure the UDF directory is enabled in `firebird.conf` (setting `UdfAccess`, default is `UdfAccess = Restrict UDF` in Firebird 2.5 and 3.0 which will allow use of the `udf` directory, note that in Firebird 4.0 the default is `UdfAccess = None`, which disables loading of UDFs).

After doing this, restart Firebird, and Firebird should then be able to load the UDF.

#### Option 2

Hunt down and remove or replace all usages of the UDF.

A query to find the dependencies of UDF `POS` is (at least for top-level dependencies of the UDF, and table/view columns):

```sql
select 
  dependent_type.RDB$TYPE_NAME dependent_type, 
  rd.RDB$DEPENDENT_NAME, 
  rrf.RDB$RELATION_NAME dependent_table,
  rrf.RDB$FIELD_NAME dependent_column,
  rf.RDB$COMPUTED_SOURCE dependent_expression,
  depended_on_type.RDB$TYPE_NAME depended_on_type, 
  rd.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_NAME 
from RDB$DEPENDENCIES rd
inner join RDB$TYPES dependent_type
  on rd.RDB$DEPENDENT_TYPE = dependent_type.RDB$TYPE and dependent_type.RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$OBJECT_TYPE'
inner join RDB$TYPES depended_on_type
  on rd.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_TYPE = depended_on_type.RDB$TYPE and depended_on_type.RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$OBJECT_TYPE' 
left join RDB$RELATION_FIELDS rrf 
  on dependent_type.RDB$TYPE_NAME IN ('COMPUTED_FIELD', 'FIELD') and rrf.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = rd.RDB$DEPENDENT_NAME 
left join RDB$FIELDS rf 
  on dependent_type.RDB$TYPE_NAME IN ('COMPUTED_FIELD', 'FIELD') and rf.RDB$FIELD_NAME = rd.RDB$DEPENDENT_NAME 
where rd.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_TYPE = 15
and rd.RDB$DEPENDED_ON_NAME = 'POS'
```

For example, if the UDF is used for a calculated column in table X, column CALCULATED_POS with expression `POS(A, B)`, then you can drop it with

```sql
alter table X drop CALCULATED_POS
```

However, if this column has dependencies, or you still need it, this might not be so easy (or not a good idea).

You can also try to alter it to remove the dependencies, by replacing the expression for an equivalent using built-in functions, or just a dummy expression to get things to work. For example, say `POS` is equivalent to the built-in [`POSITION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-position), then you could do something like:

```sql
alter table X alter CALCULATED_POS generated always as (POSITION(A, B))
```

You will need to make similar modifications if the dependencies is used in a view, check constraint (listed as a trigger), trigger or stored procedure.

Comment: An option I did not address in my answer is to write a (dummy) UDF library that provides a placeholder for those UDFs, but that can be hard to do, especially as the ABI of the function must be compatible to make it (correctly) callable by Firebird.