# Firebird "function FN_ROUND is not defined module name or entrypoint could not be found" when selecting a table

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1

I am working with a very old .FDB database that runs on Firebird v2.1.5.18497 32-bits. I am currently dumping all the data of the tables to CSV files using DBeaver so I can import it to MSSQL. However there's a single table that is having this error during the export process:

> SQL Error [335544343] [HY000]: invalid request BLR at offset 2;
> function FN_ROUND is not defined; module name or entrypoint could not
> be found [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544343]   invalid request
> BLR at offset 2; function FN_ROUND is not defined; module name or
> entrypoint could not be found [SQLState:HY000, ISC error
> code:335544343]   invalid request BLR at offset 2; function FN_ROUND
> is not defined; module name or entrypoint could not be found
> [SQLState:HY000, ISC error code:335544343]
> invalid request BLR at offset 2
> invalid request BLR at offset 2
> function FN_ROUND is not defined; module name or entrypoint could not be found

I tried selecting that table using FlameRobin and I am getting the same error:

> Engine Code    : 335544343 Engine Message : invalid request BLR at
> offset 2 function FN_ROUND is not defined module name or entrypoint
> could not be found

[image]

Upon my inspection to the table, one of the columns seems to be using this function as shown here:

[image]

I am confused why this happens since the function is already at the "Functions" category on FlameRobin:

[image]

And I am able to view the details of this function as well:

[image]

I tried switching the `UdfAccess` from the `firebird.conf` between `Unrestricted` and `Full` which I referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73025543/8331324) but it doesn't work. Can someone help me point out what seems to be wrong?

Comment: Never *ever* set `UdfAccess` to `Full`, always use `None` (no UDFs) or `Restrict` with a list of locations. In any case, the error means that the server does not have a UDF library called `INTFUNC` providing a function called `FN_ROUND`. As an aside, Firebird 2.1 has been end-of-life for nearly a decade, and 2.1.5 is not even the latest version of the 2.1 series...

Comment: In other words, find the custom UDF library (probably called intfunc.dll or something like that), and list its containing directory in the `UdfAccess` setting. Alternatively, alter the table to remove its reference to this UDF (probably a computed column).